# Como saber si una instancia esta en single user?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la instancia de producción que me ha estado dando problemas con el rendimiento, me puse a revisar de (pi a pa) después de hacer casi todo, se me vino a la mente revisar si tengo la instancia en single_user (por recomendacion de un amigo), cosa que no se si esta en single_user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes información en [este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/databases/set-a-database-to-single-user-mode?view=sql-server-ver15)

El modo de usuario único (single_user) se suele utilizar para operaciones de mantenimiento y especifica que solo un usuario puede tener acceso a la base de datos cada vez.

Para saber el modo en el que se encuentra una base de datos es ncesario hacer una consula

```
SELECT user_access_desc FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'Tu_BaseDeDatos'
```

Para pasar de single_user a multi_user debes hace lo siguiente:

```
USE MASTER;
GO

ALTER DATABASE [my_db] SET MULTI_USER:
GO
```

Comment: Ojo esto no contesta la pregunta (para nada)

Comment: @gbianchi, no la contesta debido a que se ha editado y cambiado

Comment: Respuesta actualizada con la nueva pregunta

Comment: La anterior tampoco la contestaba, por eso le deje un comentario a ver cual era realmente la pregunta. A veces hay que esperar a que la pregunta se aclare ;)